# How to connect Qt combobox with pushbutton and some kind of widget that shows picture?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qcombobox, qpushbutton

I've just started to learn Qt and I want to make a simple program where I could select a picture name (in combobox) then click the pushbutton and selected picture would appear in widget(?) (in the same window if it's possible). 
[**It should look like this:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbnEp.png)

The biggest problem that I've faced so far is connecting all those objects together, I can't make them work properly.

Also I've tried to upload picture to widget but it appears only in full size and my program becomes a picture and nothing else.

EDIT:

I am trying to make it work, but I can't achieve that..
**That's my code:**

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int index)), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked(int index)));
}
void MainWindow::choiceChanged(int index)
{

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
    firstPicture();
    break;
    case 1:
    secondPicture();
    break;
    case 2:
    thirdPicture();
    break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(int index)
{
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(on_pushButton_clicked(int)), this, SLOT(choiceChanged(int)));
}
void MainWindow::firstPicture(){
    QPixmap image("C:/Documents/Aaaa.png");
    ui->label->setPixmap(image);
}
void MainWindow::secondPicture(){
    QPixmap image("C:/Documents/Bbbb.png");
    ui->label->setPixmap(image);
}
void MainWindow::thirdPicture(){
    QPixmap image("C:/Documents/Cccc.png");
    ui->label->setPixmap(image);
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots: 
    void on_pushButton_clicked(int index);

    void choiceChanged(int index);

    void on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index);

    void firstPicture();

    void secondPicture();

    void thirdPicture();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? Did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your layout is ok but i suggest you use a QLabel to show the image.

So that's what I would do:

1. On the controller class create an attribute to store the current combo box selection, maybe an integer or a string.
2. connect to the signal changhed of the combobox a slot. (Easy way: right click on the combobox in the editor and select "Go to slot", then choose the `currentIndexChanged(int index)` or the string variation. See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop))
3. In the slot keep our variable updated so that each time you change the value on the combobox you change also the variable that will store its current state.
4. Create a slot for the push button (same thing as the combobox. Use signal `clicked()`). In the slot you than insert te picture in the QLabel.
5. To set the picture do:

   ```
   QPixmap image("/path/to/image/chosen/image.jpg"); //choose the path accordingly to the variable stored that mirrors the state of the combobox.
   ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(image); //change imageLabel to the name of your label.
   ```
6. You are good to go.

Comment: Can you please comment all those steps in more detail?
Is attribute == variable? 
I am not sure which one should I use, integer or string (In combobox there will be a few sentences)
How to keep variable updated?
I almost know how to use connect() function, this is what I've got so far:
'connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)), this, SLOT((const QString &arg1)));'

Comment: Yes variable is the attribute of the controller class that keeps track of the changes

Comment: You keep it updated through the slot listening for a change in the combo box